# how we can add custom Datacard inside Fluid Grid

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

We have a Fluid Grid named "canvas_contractform2":-

[image]

and we need to copy/paste 2 DataCards (DatacardApprovercontrols + DataCardApproverForm).. but seems there is not any option to copy the DataCards and advice?

**EDIT** This what i get when i click on the 3 dots (...):-

[image]

Comment: When you click on ellipses/three dots (...) next to datacard control, do you see the "copy" option?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no i only got 4 options (Delete, Rename, Collapse all, expand all).. i updated my question with a screen shot..

Comment: @GaneshSanap any advice ?

Comment: Can you explained the steps you followed to add these fluid data cards in your app? Also, try selecting data card control, then Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V to copy/paste the controls.

Comment: @GaneshSanap this app was created by another user, so i do not know exactly how these get added,, also CTRL + C --> CTRL + V will not copy paste